# Why the values are not getting printed in smarty template?

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

The array $data which is assigned to smarty template is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [pt_id] => 2
    [pt_doc_title] => Happy New Year
    [pt_doc_id] => 
    [delete_flag] => 
    [pt_doc_file_iname] => array.txt
)
```

To assign it to smarty template I used following code line:

```
$smarty->assign('data', $data);
```

Now currently this array is containing only one element but there may be more such elements into this array as the array is going to be generated dynamically. So for accessing the values I wrote following code, but I'm not getting anymore values over there.

```
{foreach from=$data item=titles key=key}
            <li id="ttl{$key+1}" class="ans_li">
              <span class="num-block">{$key+1}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
              <label>{'Document Title'|signal_on_error:$error_msg:'correct_ans'} <span class="reqd"> * </span></label>
              <input type="text" name="pt_doc_title[{$key+1}]" id="pt_doc_title_{$key+1}" value="{$titles.pt_doc_title}">
              <p class="uploadBtn"><input type="file" name="document_file_name_{$key+1}" id="document_file_name_{$key+1}">
              </p>
              {if $titles.pt_doc_file_iname!= ""}
                <a href="package_type_documents.php?op=download&pt_id={$titles.pt_id}&pt_doc_id={$titles.pt_doc_id}" style="font-size:small;">{$titles.pt_doc_file_iname}</a>

                <input type="checkbox" name="delete_file_{$key+1}" id="delete_file_{$key+1}" class="custom-check" />
                <label for="show">Delete file</label>                
              {else}                             
                <p class="custom-form">
                <a href="#" id="ttl{$key+1}" onclick="delete_title(this.id);return false;" class="c-delete">Delete</a>
                </p>                
              {/if}
              <input type="hidden" name="pt_doc_id[{$key}]" value="{$titles.pt_doc_id}">
              {if $titles.pt_doc_file_iname!=''}
              <input type="hidden" name="pt_doc_file_iname[{$key}]" value="{$titles.pt_doc_file_iname}">  
              {/if}
            </li>
            {/foreach}
```

So am I making any mistake in accessing the above array in smarty? Please help me in correcting my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you have an array with more then 1 element?

Comment: @Nanne:In above case there

Comment: if data is an array of arrays, you could have this array as the single element, but now it is an array with multiple elements. maybe you meant to assign that array to `$data[]`, or do `$smarty->assign('data', array(data));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [multidimensional array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) for your array.

Something like this.

```
   $data = array
    (
        0 => array(
            'pt_id' => 2,
            'pt_doc_title' => 'Happy New Year',
            'pt_doc_id' => ,
            'delete_flag' => ,
            'pt_doc_file_iname' => 'array.txt'
         )
         1 => array(
            'pt_id' => 3,
            'pt_doc_title' => 'Some other title',
            'pt_doc_id' => ,
            'delete_flag' => ,
            'pt_doc_file_iname' => 'array2.txt'
         )

    )

$smarty->assign('data', $data);
```